# Managing MySQL datavase structure with SVN?

Tags: mysql, svn

There is a SVN repository. When the trunk/ in the repository updates, our scripts automatically update our testing server. When branches/stable/ updates, our scripts automatically update our main Web server.

There is also two MySQL databases: for the main server and for the testing server.

I'd like to also manage the SQL database structure with SVN. Note that I'd like to manage only *structure* not the data in the database.

Is it possible to extract and manage with SVN *only* the structure of the MySQL database not its data?

Answer (score 1):

Dump your database structure with

```
mysqldump --no-data schema_name > schema_name.sql
```

and commit that file to your SVN repository